# Facebook sharing shows more than one miniature

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, sharing

[Debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.casadoheroi.com.br) is showing no errors or warnings, my `og:image` is 200x200, and even then I get other 2 miniatures in the share page in facebook.

I tried to explode the `og:image` to 1000x1000 and then it was the 1st option presented instead of the actual 3rd, so I think the image size of those 2 other images are the matter.

I saw that the `og:image` should be the only miniature offered, once it's validated.

I would like it to be so, please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I'm not the only one, it's a bug in facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239522122851150?browse=search_51337c9877acf8202975193